# Laravel: take(1)->count(); what does this mean?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am studying the source code of a package, [rtConner/laravel-tagging](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging/). In this package there is a trait called [TaggableTrait](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging/blob/laravel-5/src/TaggableTrait.php). On line 179, in a method called addTag(), there is this line which I don't understand:

`$previousCount = $this->tagged()->where('tag_slug', '=', $tagSlug)->take(1)->count();`

What does this line do? In specific, my problem is with `->take(1)->count();` part, are we taking 1 of the entries from the where clause and then count it?

Comment: Looks like logic here is to take first one that matches tag_slug and count how many you got. So it returns 1 or 0. It's way of type juggling i guess. Count is there so we get number and not an object of tagged.

Comment: It would make sense only along with `groupBy`. Otherwise it's redundant, as already stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Laravel documentation:

> take(int $value)
>
> Alias to set the "limit" value of the query.

So basically what you do is constructing a query with [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) and you are literally saying:

> Select count of all tags, where tag_slug is $tagSlug and return the first row

It is equal to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags WHERE tag_slug = 'blabla' LIMIT 1
```

Since [COUNT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) is aggregate function it will always return one row (count of all rows that match the where condition), so `->take(1)` is obselote and will give you the same result with or without it.

Comment: Isn't the `LIMIT` applied before `COUNT()`?

Comment: No, you can see the order of which statements are emulated and executed on the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) page. Limit is applied after all filtering is done and we have a rowset.

Comment: I see. Then it's indeed obsolete.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Ah sorry, did not saw that.